# How can I delay a reactive Meteor template from updating an HTML template variable, when a Meteor.call() updates the database instantly?

Tags: meteor

I'm developing a keno game. When the user presses the start button a Meteor.Call() executes everything for that card pick.  Including updating the user balance.  I have a setTimeout for the winning numbers, so that they display over a period of about 20 seconds.  The problem is that when the call is made, the balance updates instantly, and then the numbers start displaying with the delay. I not familiar with how to solve this.  I appreciate any help.

server-side:

```
Meteor.methods({
    process: function(){
        // generate numbers
        // update user balance
    }
});
```

client-side:

```
Template.keno.events({
    'click #start' : function(){
        Meteor.call('process',function(err,numbers){
            //setTimeout on displaying numbers
            // as setTimeout displays numbers, balance already updated. I need to delay
            // the balance update, until all numbers are displayed. 
            // otherwise, the player see that they won before all numbers come out.
        });
    }
});
```

** Update **

The only help I need is to understand how to make a variable like {{balance}} unreactive, until I finish the setTimeout, and then have it update.  Should I be using sessions?  Should I not use a template variable and instead, insert the balance with jquery?  It's just a simple solution, the difficulty is that I don't know what function / method I'm looking for that can help me turn off the reactivity for a set amount of time, and then update, after the Meteor.call() for then numbers finishes it's setTimeout.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your situation correctly, you need the template {{balance}} expression to be set at a time you decide vs. when the collection gets a result from the server. So you could use Session to set a value when you like. Below is an example:

```
<body>
  {{> game}}
</body>

<template name="game">
  <button id="process">Process</button>
  <div>{{firstNumber}}</div>
  <div>{{secondNumber}}</div>
  <div>balance: {{balance}}</div>
</template>

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.game.events({
    'click #process': function (e, tmpl) {
      Meteor.call('process', function (err, result) {
        Session.set('firstNumber', result[0]);
        setTimeout(function () {
          Session.set('secondNumber', result[1]);
          Session.set('balance', result[0] + result[1]);
        }, 2000);
      });
    }
  });

  Template.game.helpers({
    firstNumber: function () { return Session.get('firstNumber'); },
    secondNumber: function () { return Session.get('secondNumber'); },
    balance: function () { return Session.get('balance'); }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  function randomNumber () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  }
  Meteor.methods({
    process: function () {
      return [randomNumber(), randomNumber()];
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your `Meteor.call()` inside the `setTimeout()` itself, like:

```
Template.keno.events({
    'click #start' : function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
               Meteor.call('process',function(){
                 //do something.
               });
         }, 20000);
     }
});
```

Comment: Remember also that the call() will take some time also, so if you want exact 20 secs you need to consider that.

Comment: Also Meteor has its own Meteor.setTimeout() method

Comment: No dice.  The call already is inside a setTimeout.  The issue is that the template is reactive, and the balance updates server-side when the numbers are generated. :(   I can post a more detailed version if that helps, but I think my example is sufficient, no?

Comment: Ok I think I understand your issue now. I'm on my phone now but might be able to help you later!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is to use reactivity on a duplicated collection :
You set your main collection on server side only.
You create another collection on the client side that will be a duplicate collection but used only for display
Then you pusblish the main collection to the client.
On the client side, you set all required observer on it that will replicate all modification on the duplicated collection. But this way you can manage animation or any other wished features. All actions on client side will do call on server-side but it won't affect immediatly the templates because the templates only use the duplicated collections.
I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I know there is an elegant solution that doesn't require much coding.  It's just hard to research an answer when you don't know the proper question / terminology to search.

Comment: Hope you will find another way. I'm interested in this kind of feature. It will improve a lot the ergonomy of MeteorJs application. On Firebase.org there a cool sample of this kind of feature : blink red when someone delete data.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I threw this demo together in 5 mins, works though.

Here's the demo: http://keno-test.meteor.com/

Of course it needs LOT's more work, but the delayed thing works.

```
HTML:
<head>
    <title>keno-test</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">

    <input id="callCardThing" type="button" value="Start card-thing" />

    <h1>Here are the cards!</h1>
    <ul>
    {{#each cards}}

        <li>{{value}}</li>

    {{/each}}
    </ul>

</template>


JS:
Cards = new Meteor.Collection('cards');

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Deps.autorun(function () {
        Meteor.subscribe("cards");
    });

    Template.hello.events({
        "click #callCardThing": function (event) {
            Meteor.call("doCardThingOnServer");
        }
    });

    Template.hello.helpers({
        cards: function () {
            return Cards.find({});
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Meteor.startup(function () {
        Meteor.publish("cards", function () {
            return Cards.find({});
        });
    });

    Meteor.methods({
        doCardThingOnServer: function () {
            // I remove all the cards every time just for the demo…
            Cards.remove({});
            var numberOfcards = 10;
            var counter = Meteor.setInterval(function () {
                Cards.insert({value: 'whatever! no: '+numberOfcards });
                numberOfcards--;
                if (numberOfcards < 1) Meteor.clearInterval(counter);
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question.  I already have a delay on the numbers, My issue is that when the balance is updated on the server, it auto updates the template, but I don't want it to update until after the numbers setTimeout finishes.

Comment: OK. So for each insert, add "hidden: 1" to each doc, and in the clearInterval-if-part, add an update to all the docs where it sets them to hidden: 0. And only subscribe the client to hidden: 0 docs.

Comment: Wont that make the balance disappear on start, and then reappear on timeout finish? Isn't there a way to disable a specific variable form being reactive?

Comment: Update the balance after the clearInterval and that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so how about conditional {{balance}} rendering?

```
var shouldRender = false;

setTimeout(function () {
  shouldRender = true;
}, 2000);

Template.template_name.shouldRender = function () {
  return shouldRender;
}

{{#if shouldRender}}
  {{>balance}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I think you have my situation backwards.  The numbers are generated on the server. It instantly debts the user's balance, and calculates wether or not the user won.  If they won, it instantly updates the database, which then instantly updates the template {{balance}}.  This happens before the setTimeout even starts displaying the numbers.  I've tried to set an additional timeout server-side, and when the timeout is over, it actually refreshes the page, clearing all the numbers.  I just want to be able to control when the balance updates.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Atmosphere animation package : https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/animation!

I've just done this package to explore one way of doing animation on database reactivity.
You have to register a cursor and the template to animate. There is a project that will show you how to do that.

I hope it will help you.