# Meteor template updates before result of Meteor.users.update

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent a template from updating until `Meteor.users.update()` finishes.

First I'm trying to make sense of the [documentation and the use of an optional callback argument](http://docs.meteor.com/#update) in order to sort out what is happening.

Here is what I have:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),
                    {$set:{'profile.reviewList': []}},
                     [],
                      function(err, result){
                            if (err){
                              console.log('oh no!');
                            } else {
                            console.log('Result achieved: '+this.profile.reviewList);
                            }
                          });
```

Currently the `console.log('Result achieved: '+this.profile.reviewList);` always returns something like `...TypeError: Cannot read property 'reviewList' of undefined...` the first time though which tells me its firing before the result comes back.

I'm sure I'm not implementing the callback properly, but I was attempting to model this answer: [How do you ensure an update has finished in meteor before running a find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597012/how-do-you-ensure-an-update-has-finished-in-meteor-before-running-a-find)

I'd really just like to delay the re-rendering of the associated template until the property gets created.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assume that scope (`this`) in callback function return `user` object, which is wrong.

If you want to get `user` object in that callback simply query it there:

```
var user = Meteor.users.find(Meteor.userId()).fetch()
```

Another thing, you passed `empty array` as 2nd argument which is not needed.

```
Meteor.users.update(
    Meteor.userId(), 
    {
        $set: {
            'profile.reviewList': 'testData'
        }
    },
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('oh no!');
        } else {
            var user = Meteor.users.find(Meteor.userId()).fetch();
            console.log('Result achieved: ' , user && user.profile && user.profile.reviewList);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: This is working, thank you. I'm not familiar with the notation used in this line ```console.log('Result achieved: ' , user && user.profile && user.profile.reviewList);``` My guess is that the console won't run until all three of those entities exist. Is this necessary? Wouldn't the console.log wait until the result is returned? Or more precisely, only if the operation is a success?

Comment: a && b is called guard operator. See [explanation how it works](http://roubenmeschian.com/rubo/?p=50)